# CenterScreen Window on Un-Maximizing, on StateChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

I have main Window which is on load set to Maximize. But when i Un-Maximize the window or double-click window's title-bar. it randomly get placed on screen anywhere but not `ScreenCenter`.

Is there any way i can place window at ScreenCenter when un-maximized

i tried the following code in hope, but didn't worked

```
private void InfoWindow_OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var window = sender as Window;
    if(window != null && window.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because WPF doesn't provide a direct method for this job, you'll need to do something like this:

```
var workingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
this.Left = (workingArea.Width - this.Width) / 2 + workingArea.Left;
this.Top = (workingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2 + workingArea.Top;
```

Comment: this  is for winforms

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to set the window position to the center of your screen.

```
private void CenterWindowOnScreen()
    {
        double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
        double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
        double windowWidth = this.Width;
        double windowHeight = this.Height;
        this.Left = (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
        this.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);
    }

private void InfoWindow_OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var window = sender as Window;
    if(window != null && window.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
      CenterWindowOnScreen();
}
```